# Why is the used heap suddenly decreasing?

Tags: java, profiling

I am just getting started with profiling in Java using VisualVM profiler. I have noticed that there is a big drop in the used heap once 700MB are reached. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: I think, when garbage collector, deletes un-referenced objects in one go, then this drop happens.

Comment: It could be that the application has made a large data structure unreachable, or that the GC decided to break a bunch of soft references.

Comment: does this mean that the garbage collector is triggered only when a maximum used heap is reached? Who decides what is the heap size?

Answer (score 1):

That's your garbage collector for more info [GC doc](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Edit : If you want to see how much memory is released when the GC executes use this JVM option :

> -verbose:gc